# Matlab vec2frames like function in python

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any function in python which works similar to Matlab vec2frames function?

Comment: There is no builtin function called vec2frames in Matlab

Comment: In continuation to Itamar's comment - did you mean [this FEX submission](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32301-framing-routines/)?